# after initial r*view here is a rewrite of my c++ timerqueue ported to rust

Tags: rust

Purpose. Provides a background task queue so that code can ask for a function to be run at a specified point in the future.  They indicate what to run (a closure) and when to run it (also a name just used for tracing). My use case is typically 2-3 items queued at any time, typical items are very fast (think read 100 bytes from a disk). Typically the executions are between 10 and 500ms in the future. It is used for the async IO subsystem in my PDP11 emulator I am porting from c++

The client receives a handle that they can query to see if their task is finished. They can also wait for it to finish.

I posted my first version and got an excellent review and have almost totally recoded it and stolen the notification handle mechanism from the reviewer too. Original Review [port of my c++ timer queue to rust](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/247327/port-of-my-c-timer-queue-to-rust)

Here is the code

```
use log::trace;
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::collections::BinaryHeap;
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::sync::mpsc::RecvTimeoutError::{Disconnected, Timeout};
use std::sync::mpsc::{Receiver, Sender};
use std::sync::{Arc, Condvar, Mutex};
use std::thread;
use std::thread::JoinHandle;
use std::time::{Duration, Instant};

pub struct TimerQueue {
    jh: Option<JoinHandle<()>>,
    tx: Sender<QueueInstruction>,
}


type TQIFunc = fn() -> ();
#[derive(Debug)]
struct TimerQueueItem {
    when: Instant, // when it should run
    name: String,  // for trace only
    what: TQIFunc, // what to run
    handle: TimerQueueHandle,
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct TimerQueueHandle {
    handle: Arc<(Mutex<bool>, Condvar)>,
}

impl TimerQueueHandle {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            handle: Arc::new((Mutex::new(false), Condvar::new())),
        }
    }

    pub fn wait(&self) {
        let (lock, cv) = &*self.handle;
        let mut finished = lock.lock().unwrap();
        while !*finished {
            finished = cv.wait(finished).unwrap();
        }
    }
    pub fn finished(&self) -> bool {
        let (lock, _cv) = &*self.handle;
        let finished = lock.lock().unwrap();
        *finished
    }
    fn signal(&self) {
        let (lock, cv) = &*self.handle;
        let mut finished = lock.lock().unwrap();
        *finished = true;
        cv.notify_all();
    }
}

enum QueueInstruction {
    Do(TimerQueueItem),
    Stop,
}

// all these Trait impls are required so that binaryheap can sort on due time
// ====================================================
impl Ord for TimerQueueItem {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &TimerQueueItem) -> Ordering {
        other.when.cmp(&self.when)
    }
}
impl PartialOrd for TimerQueueItem {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &TimerQueueItem) -> Option<Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(other))
    }
}
impl PartialEq for TimerQueueItem {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.when == other.when
    }
}
impl Eq for TimerQueueItem {}
// ====================================================

enum GetItemResult {
    Timeout,
    Stop,
    NewItem(TimerQueueItem),
}
// either we got a new tqi, were told to stop or timed out
// timeout indicates that we need to (probably ) run the top of the queue
// called in one of 2 ways - duration == 0 , wait forever, duration != 0, wait that long
// maybe should be an option
fn get_item(rx: &Receiver<QueueInstruction>, wait: Duration) -> GetItemResult {
    let mut stop = false;
    let mut timeout = false;
    let mut qinst = QueueInstruction::Stop; // init to something
    if wait == Duration::from_secs(0) {
        match rx.recv() {
            Ok(qinstx) => qinst = qinstx,
            Err(_) => stop = true,
        };
    } else {
        match rx.recv_timeout(wait) {
            Ok(qinstx) => qinst = qinstx,
            Err(e) => match e {
                Timeout => timeout = true,
                Disconnected => stop = true,
            },
        };
    }
    if stop {
        GetItemResult::Stop
    } else if timeout {
        GetItemResult::Timeout
    } else {
        match qinst {
            QueueInstruction::Do(tqi) => {
                trace!(target:"TimerQueue","got item {}", tqi.name);
                GetItemResult::NewItem(tqi)
            }
            QueueInstruction::Stop => {
                trace!("got stop request");
                GetItemResult::Stop
            }
        }
    }
}

impl TimerQueue {
    pub fn new() -> TimerQueue {
        let (tx, rx): (Sender<QueueInstruction>, Receiver<QueueInstruction>) = mpsc::channel();
        let jh = thread::spawn(move || {
            let mut queue: BinaryHeap<TimerQueueItem> = BinaryHeap::new();
            let mut stop = false;
            loop {
                if queue.len() == 0 {
                    if stop {
                        break;
                    }
                    match get_item(&rx, Duration::from_secs(0)) {
                        GetItemResult::Stop => {
                            break; // no work and a request to stop - so stop
                        }
                        GetItemResult::NewItem(i) => {
                            queue.push(i);
                        }
                        GetItemResult::Timeout => panic!(), // cannot actually happen here
                    }
                } else {
                    let now = Instant::now();
                    let tqi = queue.peek().expect("oops");
                    let due = tqi.when;
                    if due > now {
                        let wait = due - now;
                        trace!(target:"TimerQueue","sleep for {0}ms", wait.as_millis());
                        match get_item(&rx, wait) {
                            GetItemResult::Stop => {
                                stop = true; // drain the queue first
                            }
                            GetItemResult::NewItem(i) => {
                                queue.push(i);
                            }
                            GetItemResult::Timeout => {
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        trace!(target:"TimerQueue","running {0}", tqi.name);
                        (tqi.what)();
                        tqi.handle.signal();
                        queue.pop().unwrap();
                    }
                }
            }
            trace!(target:"TimerQueue", "thread completed");
        });

        TimerQueue { jh: Some(jh), tx }
    }

    pub fn queue(&self, f: TQIFunc, n: String, when: Instant) -> TimerQueueHandle {
        let handle = TimerQueueHandle::new();
        trace!(target:"TimerQueue", "queued {0}", &n);
        let qi = TimerQueueItem {
            what: f,
            name: n,
            when: when,
            handle: handle.clone(),
        };
        let qinst = QueueInstruction::Do(qi);
        self.tx.send(qinst).unwrap();
        handle
    }
}

impl Drop for TimerQueue {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        self.tx.send(QueueInstruction::Stop).unwrap();
        match self.jh.take() {
            Some(jh) => jh.join().unwrap(),
            None => {}
        }
    }
}
fn main() {
    env_logger::init();

    let tq = TimerQueue::new();
    tq.queue(
        || {
            println!("1 sec");
        },
        String::from("1 sec"),
        Instant::now() + Duration::from_millis(1000),
    );

    let h5 = tq.queue(
        || println!("5 sec"),
        String::from("5 sec"),
        Instant::now() + Duration::from_millis(5000),
    );

    tq.queue(
        || {
            println!("1 sec");
        },
        String::from("1 sec"),
        Instant::now() + Duration::from_millis(1000),
    );

    let h3 = tq.queue(
        || {
            println!("3 sec");
        },
        String::from("3 sec"),
        Instant::now() + Duration::from_millis(3000),
    );

    h3.wait();
    println!("h3 done");
    println!("h5 is finised {}", h5.finished());
    h5.wait();
    println!("h5 is finised {}", h5.finished());
}
```

sorry it fairly long

Comment: Hello, to better clarify scope of your project you could add a reference link to the previous post your actual question is a follow up.

Comment: @dariosicily here u go https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/247327/port-of-my-c-timer-queue-to-rust